# SVG vs VML - has either been deprecated by browser vendors?

Tags: svg, vml

We are converting a DOCX file to HTML. In the DOCX file it has Shapes & SmartArt which we can render as SVG or VML.

Is there any official statement by the browser vendors as to which is preferred? Or which will continue to be updated while the other is just maintained?

I am **not** asking for an opinion of which is better. I am just asking if one has been deprecated by the browser vendors.

**Reply to being closed:** How on earth is asking if VML is deprecated a duplicate of detecting which is supported in a browser?

Comment: No current browser supports VML

Comment: @RobertLongson - I just tried both chrome & Edge and they both display VML fine.

Comment: @DavidThielen "*VML is not natively supported by most web browsers. Web browsers such as Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Safari or Google Chrome support SVG instead of VML.*" - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language#Implementations)

Comment: Chrome has never supported VML and Edge does not support it either so I've no idea what you're doing but you're clearly not using VML. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801223(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VML is officially deprecated. See here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801223(v=vs.85).aspx

It's a miracle it works at all for you.

Comment: Thank you. We're using SVG but seeing Word use VML had me worried that we were going down the wrong road. Nice to know SVG is correct.